# About loops and variables in Python

Tags: python, loops, variables, store

I'm new to the world of programming so this might be a stupid question but anyway, here it is.

Is it possible to define a special kind of variable which would remember its previous value and carry this value from one loop to the next? Hm... Now I'm not even sure I formulated the question correctly but in essence what I would like to do is to start with a variable (`var = 0`), then change it to (`var += 10`) in the same loop if a condition is met. In the next loop the variable should be now (`var = 10`) and if the condition is met again, the variable will be (`var += 10`) which should be (`var = 20`), and so on. It is like a 'reincarnated' variable which remembers its past life. I hope it makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: If a variable is defined outside the loop then it will meet your demand.

Comment: I thought about that and it for some reason it didn't work. But now I wrote the whole script again and it works. I must have missed something. Details, details... Thank you!

Comment: One more question. Are there also other ways to affect specific iterations of a loop and which are those ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
var = 0
while var >= 0:
    if <condition met>:
        var += 10
```

Comment: No worries, could you mark this answer as having answered your question if you found it useful?

Answer (score 3):

You can just declare the variable before the loop and its value will persist through each iteration.

Python 2:

```
x = 0
for i in range(0, 10):
    print "i is %d and x is %d" % (i, x)
    x += 10
```

Python 3:

```
x = 0
for i in range(0, 10):
    print("i is {0} and x is {1}".format(i, x))
    x += 10
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will add 10 to x when y is 1,4,7 or 9. Also maintains a list (xl) containing previous values of x. So, current and previous values of x are available.

```
x = 0
xl = []

for y in range(0, 10):
    if y in (1,4,7,9):
        x = x+10;
        xl.append(x)


print (x)
print (xl)
```

Comment: Interesting! Thank you!